# HTTP Request: Is there any ways to share cookies keeping the wild card access origin?

Tags: cookies, request, axios

I am using Axios to make http request. I need to share my cookies with every individual request. Each and every solutions out there contains only one answer just set

> withCredentials: true

But I can not use it because it says

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin in response header can not 't set to
>   wildcard (*)

Which I can not change as my app will distributed as independent mobile app. so I don't know what will be the domain client requesting from.

So again my question is, Is there any other ways to share cookies keeping the wild card access origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over the server, you don't have to return a wildcard. Every request will have an `Origin` header which contains the domainname of where the request originated from.

So you can take the value of this request header, and put the value in the `Acccess-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: This is a great idea. Thanks